# Wordpress WP_Comment_Query - No Spaces

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using the WP_Comment_Query to bring back specific comments...

The problem is it's not formatting the comment correctly, if they enter a carriage return it just ignores them and shows the raw text with no formatting...

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Is there a reason why you not use [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)?

Comment: Becuase we are styling the theme slightly differently...

Comment: Formatting problems in DB? Could you post the query?

Comment: I've just tried using the get_comments(); but it still doesn't format it properly... it's a really simple query:

$comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID,
        ));

Comment: and you use [comment_content]?

Comment: This seems to work apply_filters('the_content', $comment->comment_author);

Comment: The only problem is, it seems to ingnore paragraphs...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44800/discussion-between-webdevb-and-ava)

Answer (score 0):

add this to functions:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

Then filter with `nl2br();`

e.g.

```
$comments = get_comments(array('post_id' => $post->ID,));
foreach ($comments as $comment){
  echo nl2br($comment->comment_content);
}
```